# Responsive Image vs specify the width and height of an image in HTML

Tags: html, css, image

I am reading about responsive design and I noticed the following problem:

One of the recommendations regarding "Fluid Images" is to use a CSS rule such as :

```
img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto; }
```

but in order for it to have the right affect we need to strip inline image width and height attributes of the img tag.

How that settle with [It’s important to specify the width and height of an image in HTML](http://blog.silktide.com/2010/09/its-important-to-specify-the-width-and-height-of-an-image-in-html/)  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 16):

Although (as I stated in my other answer) the `width` and `height` attributes do not interfere with fluid images, fluid images do interfere with not-yet-loaded images taking up the proper amount of space in browsers other than Chrome.  There is a workaround for this: wrap the image in a div with an intrinsic ratio, as described in this article: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video/

```
.img-wrapper {
    max-width: 200px; /* The actual width of the image */
}

.img-wrapper2 {
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%; /* The image's height divided by its width */
}
```

Unfortunately this requires two wrapper divs, in order to get the max-width effect right.  However, it does provide the same advantages to apparent loading speed that the `width` and `height` attributes provide.  You may want to give `.img-wrapper` `overflow: hidden` to hide some of the pathological behavior of older IE.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7j3db/32/

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to strip the image width and height attributes.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7j3db/

Tested in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE9 and IE9 emulating IE7.  Seems to work fine in all of them, with the exact CSS rule you mentioned.

EDIT: Tested with an image that could not be loaded: http://jsfiddle.net/7j3db/1/

This had the proper effect in Chrome and IE (even IE7), but not in Firefox or Opera.  However, even in Firefox and Opera, the effect was better than if the width and height attributes were left out (because the width attribute still had an effect, even though the height attribute didn't).

Further testing with alt text (http://jsfiddle.net/7j3db/2/): Handled perfectly by IE7, but IE9 joins Opera, and IE8 does something really strange (the image height depends on the length of the alt text - the more alt text, the less space).  Chrome seems to ignore the alt text entirely.  Opera and FF show the alt text, but otherwise have essentially the same behavior as they did before.  The width and height attributes do not appear to be responsible for any of these alt text woes, however (except in IE8, to some extent).

Comment: Actually, Firefox's behavior was to not show the image at all when it couldn't be loaded - but it could be made to behave like Opera by putting `display: inline-block` on the image.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I tried when I left the width and height inside the img tag then the image didn't scale when the layout viewport size changed.I think as the inline width and height are local they are stronger then the CSS rule. To me it looks like I can remove the width and height attributes and then I will have "Fluid Images" that scale with the change of the viewport's  size and sacrifice page load speed or to leave those attribute and to sacrifice the "Fluid Images" pros. In case I am right  how I choose what to sacrifice .

Comment: In terms of CSS, values set via attributes in the HTML (i.e. width= and height=) are minimum priority, whereas values set via CSS in a "style" attribute are maximum priority.  Hence the justification for the behavior of Opera, Firefox and IE9, which is to ignore "height=" entirely if you set a height (even `height: auto`) in your CSS.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by adding

```
html, body{
max-width:100%;
width:100%;
}
```

and also putting these properties on the parent div of the img tag.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. Also when using images without a fixed width/height attr you can use the property `height:auto` keeping all images in scale.